# Running a single MFTF test that is included within a suite

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2, testing, mftf

I am trying to only run the test [StorefrontVerifySecureURLRedirectCheckout](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.2/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Test/Mftf/Test/StorefrontVerifySecureURLRedirectCheckoutTest.xml). To run it I am using the following command:
`vendor/bin/mftf run:test StorefrontVerifySecureURLRedirectCheckout -k`
(I have to use `-k` to skip generating due to an error see the update)

When executing the above command it executes much more tests than just the desired one:

```
Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework.functional Tests (935) ----------------------
Modules: \Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Module\MagentoWebDriver, \Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Helper\Acceptance, \Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Helper\MagentoFakerData, \Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Module\MagentoSequence, \Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Module\MagentoAssert, Asserts
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AdminAddConfigurableProductWithDropDownAttributeAndCustomSourceTestCest:
Signature: Magento\AcceptanceTest\_MSI_Multi_Mode\Backend\AdminAddConfigurableProductWithDropDownAttributeAndCustomSourceTestCest:AdminAddConfigurableProductWithDropDownAttributeAndCustomSourceTest
Test: tests/functional/Magento/FunctionalTest/_generated/MSI_Multi_Mode/AdminAddConfigurableProductWithDropDownAttributeAndCustomSourceTestCest.php:AdminAddConfigurableProductWithDropDownAttributeAndCustomSourceTest
Scenario --

/******** Beginning execution of MSI_Multi_Mode suite before block ********/
[...]
/******** Execution of MSI_Multi_Mode suite before block complete ********/
[...]
AdminAddConfigurableProductWithDropDownAttributeWithNewSourceTestCest: Admin add configurable product with drop down attribute with new source test
Signature: Magento\AcceptanceTest\_MSI_Multi_Mode\Backend\AdminAddConfigurableProductWithDropDownAttributeWithNewSourceTestCest:AdminAddConfigurableProductWithDropDownAttributeWithNewSourceTest
Test: tests/functional/Magento/FunctionalTest/_generated/MSI_Multi_Mode/AdminAddConfigurableProductWithDropDownAttributeWithNewSourceTestCest.php:AdminAddConfigurableProductWithDropDownAttributeWithNewSourceTest
Scenario --
[..]
```

It seems like the whole **MSI_Multi_Mode** suite is being executed.

I've tried it with the example provided in the [getting started guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/docs/getting-started.html#run-tests) and this works just fine. Only [AdminLoginTestCest](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.2/app/code/Magento/Backend/Test/Mftf/Test/AdminLoginTest.xml) is executed.

I've compared both tests but I didn't find any difference that could lead to such a behavior.

**Update:**
I found the following in the [official docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/docs/test.html#principles):

> If `<test>` is included in `<suite>`, it cannot be generated in isolation to the rest of the contents of the suite (see suites for details).

If I understand it correctly is that if a test is included it cannot be run separately.

The test **StorefrontVerifySecureURLRedirectCheckout** actually is defined in the suite **SecureStorefrontURLSuite** due to [SecureStorefrontURLSuite.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.2/app/code/Magento/Store/Test/Mftf/Suite/SecureStorefrontURLSuite.xml) which includes the group **secure_storefront_url**.

When executing `vendor/bin/mftf run:test StorefrontVerifySecureURLRedirectCheckout` without the `-k` argument as written above it will result in the following error:

```
In TestGenerator.php line 147:

  Cannot reference test configuration for generation without accompanying suite.
```

**How is it possible to run a single test that is included in a suite?**

A possible solution might be to create a new suite that only includes this one test but it doesn't seems more like a hack to me and it's quite some effort to always create or change suites just to run a single test. I wonder if there is any other solution for this problem.

**Update 2:**
I just verified, it is possible to wrap the single test in a suite and then execute the suite with `vendor/bin/mftf run:group SingleTestSuiteName --remove` but this **IS NOT** really an solution/answer I am looking for due to the inconveniences it brings with having to keep changing the suite all the time.